# Flowing Water in Byte Array based Terrain

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, graph-theory, terrain

I am using a byte array to describe the terrain in my game, each byte value represents a different block type

I created a grid to simulate the water spread, I'm giving a byte value to the amount of water on a block and then I am spreading it by increasing the value of one block which causes it to spread to blocks that have less water, I made a little video of it to show: ( value 55 is a wall, 0 air, 1 to 4 water, its a top down perspective )

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOmnejfmPe0

However I am having trouble finishing it, I dont want the water level to rise above 4, when a block that is already at value 4 goes to 5 I want it to flow through all the other blocks until all the contained water is at value 4. However with my current code if I set the condition so that the water flows no matter what if it has value of 4 or more it ends in infinite loop.

here is the current relevant code:

```
 public Vector3Int PosToCheck;
    public IEnumerator FlowRoutine(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        PosToCheck = KeepPosInBounds(new Vector3Int(x - 1, y, z));
        if ( GridArray[x,y,z] > GridArray[PosToCheck.x,PosToCheck.y,PosToCheck.z] + 1  && GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] != 55)
        {
            GridArray[x, y, z] -= 1;
            GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] += 1;

            yield return StartCoroutine(FlowRoutine(PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z));
        }
        else
        {
            PosToCheck = KeepPosInBounds(new Vector3Int(x, y + 1, z));
            if (GridArray[x,y,z] > GridArray[PosToCheck.x,PosToCheck.y,PosToCheck.z] + 1  && GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] != 55)
            {
                GridArray[x, y, z] -= 1;
                GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] += 1;

                yield return StartCoroutine(FlowRoutine(PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z));
            }
            else
            {
                PosToCheck = KeepPosInBounds(new Vector3Int(x + 1, y, z));
                if (GridArray[x,y,z] > GridArray[PosToCheck.x,PosToCheck.y,PosToCheck.z] + 1  && GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] != 55)
                {
                    GridArray[x, y, z] -= 1;
                    GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] += 1;

                    yield return StartCoroutine(FlowRoutine(PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z));
                }
                else
                {
                    PosToCheck = KeepPosInBounds(new Vector3Int(x , y-1, z));
                    if (GridArray[x,y,z] > GridArray[PosToCheck.x,PosToCheck.y,PosToCheck.z] + 1  && GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] != 55)
                    {
                        GridArray[x, y, z] -= 1;
                        GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] += 1;

                        yield return StartCoroutine(FlowRoutine(PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        UpdateAllButtons();

        yield return null;
    }

    public Vector3Int KeepPosInBounds(Vector3Int newPos)
    {
        if (newPos.x < 0) { newPos.x = XGridSize - 1; }
        if (newPos.y < 0) { newPos.y = YGridSize - 1; }
        if (newPos.z < 0) { newPos.z = ZGridSize - 1; }
        if (newPos.x >= XGridSize) { newPos.x = 0; }
        if (newPos.y >= YGridSize) { newPos.y = 0; }
        if (newPos.z >= ZGridSize) { newPos.z = 0; }

        return newPos;
    }
```

and this is the condition I was trying to add but it breaks before all available blocks are at 4, ( water gets caught in an infinite loop between 2 blocks that pass water to each other infinitely)

```
    if ((GridArray[x,y,z] > GridArray[PosToCheck.x,PosToCheck.y,PosToCheck.z] + 1 || GridArray[x, y, z]>=WaterCap) && GridArray[PosToCheck.x, PosToCheck.y, PosToCheck.z] != 55)
```

Would appreciate advice on how to tackle this problem, Thanks!

Comment: Ironically, I think you may want to consider some kind of pathfinding algorithm for this. Consider the world where it is almost all water 4, only with one location that is water 5, and one location that is water 3. What kind of algorithm could determine which 4 to flow into the 3, and which 4 to flow the 5 onto; such that the 5 most directly ends up adjacent to the 3 so that the whole map can be water 4 on the next flow? Seems like a tricky challenge!

Comment: I'm putting the [tag:unity3d] back in because this may need to consider how Unity implements coroutines. I'm also adding [tag:graph-theory] as a more specific replacement for [tag:logic]. Hopefully someone takes a shot at this. I'm interested in what solutions people come up with.

Comment: ah also I'm not 100% attached to coroutines, I'm just using them so eventually when I have big amounts of watter flowing at the same time i can look at whats happening slowly

Comment: For the pathfinding solution, How would I go about collecting all possible cells for a certain pool of water? Thinking with dynamic terrains I wouldn't at first know where in the map water should or shouldn't be flowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the behavior you are looking for?

[image: Demo]

Assuming you have a 2D grid of byte type, you can use DFS or BFS to achieve this.
In my case, I made a Cell class having the Value property which when set, updates the cell's text and color automatically.

Next, I made a grid manager storing the 2D grid of Cells. The trigger function resides in the manager. Whenever I trigger a certain cell, It runs a DFS to update starting from this cell. The DFS logic has conditions to check for bounds and walls and also restricts the overflow of water.

```
void Trigger(int x, int y)
{
    bool[,] visited = new bool[yCount, xCount];

    for(int i=0; i<yCount; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<xCount; j++)
        {
            visited[i, j] = false;
        }
    }

    DfsUpdate(y, x, visited);
}

void DfsUpdate(int i, int j, bool[,] visited)
{
    // Check out of bounds
    if (i < 0 || i >= yCount) return;
    if (j < 0 || j >= xCount) return;

    if (visited[i, j]) return;

    // Mark as visited
    visited[i, j] = true;

    if (cells[i, j].Value == 55) // Its a wall
        return;

    if (cells[i, j].Value == 0)
    {
        // Needs 1 update and return
        cells[i, j].Value++;
        return;
    }

    // Restrict upto 4 if its water
    cells[i, j].Value = (byte) Mathf.Min(cells[i, j].Value + 1, 4);

    // Recursively call neighbouting cells
    DfsUpdate(i + 1, j, visited);
    DfsUpdate(i - 1, j, visited);
    DfsUpdate(i, j + 1, visited);
    DfsUpdate(i, j - 1, visited);
}
```

You can use BFS too but DFS works fine here and implementation is easier in case of DFS.

Edit:

It takes 72 clicks to fill the grid now. Check the bottom left to see the mouse click count.

[image: Updated Preview]

I changed the code. Now when I click on a cell, if it is already 4 (filled), it finds for the nearest grid that's not completely filled and adds 1 to it else it fills itself.
In the Update method, I iterate over the grid at a certain rate and check if there are any cells having a neighbor such that their water levels have a difference of two. I fill that cell and mark it as updated so that they don't get updated again in the current frame.

The grid update method is a simple BFS which adds 1 to the nearest non-filled neighbor if any exists.

In the update method, using a timer, whenever a certain delay is crossed, I iterate over the grid to even out the water level differences.

Here is the code.

```
void GridUpdate(int i, int j)
{
    bool[,] visited = new bool[yCount, xCount];
    Queue<int> iQ = new Queue<int>();
    Queue<int> jQ = new Queue<int>();
    iQ.Enqueue(i);
    jQ.Enqueue(j);

    while(iQ.Count > 0)
    {
        int si = iQ.Dequeue();
        int sj = jQ.Dequeue();

        if (!CheckBounds(si, sj)) continue;

        if (cells[si, sj].Value == 55) continue;

        if (cells[si, sj].Value < 4)
        {
            cells[si, sj].Value++;
            return;
        }

        // Up
        iQ.Enqueue(si - 1);
        jQ.Enqueue(sj);

        // Down
        iQ.Enqueue(si + 1);
        jQ.Enqueue(sj);

        // Left
        iQ.Enqueue(si);
        jQ.Enqueue(sj - 1);

        // Right
        iQ.Enqueue(si);
        jQ.Enqueue(sj + 1);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime * 1000f;
    if (timer >= updateDelay)
    {
        timer -= updateDelay;
        bool[,] updated = new bool[yCount, xCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < yCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < xCount; j++)
            {
                if (updated[i, j] || cells[i,j].Value == 55) continue;

                if (CheckBounds(i-1, j) && !updated[i-1, j] && cells[i, j].Value - cells[i - 1, j].Value >= 2)
                {
                    updated[i - 1, j] = true;
                    cells[i - 1, j].Value++;
                    cells[i, j].Value--;
                }
                else if (CheckBounds(i+1, j) && !updated[i + 1, j] && cells[i, j].Value - cells[i + 1, j].Value >= 2)
                {
                    updated[i + 1, j] = true;
                    cells[i + 1, j].Value++;
                    cells[i, j].Value--;
                }
                else if (CheckBounds(i, j-1) && !updated[i, j-1] && cells[i, j].Value - cells[i, j-1].Value >= 2)
                {
                    updated[i, j-1] = true;
                    cells[i, j-1].Value++;
                    cells[i, j].Value--;
                }
                else if (CheckBounds(i, j+1) && !updated[i, j + 1] && cells[i, j].Value - cells[i, j + 1].Value >= 2)
                {
                    updated[i, j + 1] = true;
                    cells[i, j + 1].Value++;
                    cells[i, j].Value--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Checks if a given i and j are not out of bounds of the grid
bool CheckBounds(int i, int j)
{
    if (j < 0 || j >= xCount) return false;
    if (i < 0 || i >= yCount) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your implementation, it looks great! There's only one problem, I didn't want 1 click to add more than 1 water into the system. In your example you clicked 10 times and the final total water in the system was 72 (18 cells each 4 water). Is there a way to progressively fill the cells so that you need 72 clicks to reach your final result? Thanks again!

Comment: I am a bit confused about the idea of 72 clicks because if in one click fills more than one bucket at a time, the answer will be less than 72. Do you want to fill only one bucket and when it is completely filled, pick a connected bucket and start filling it? That way you will get 72 clicks. But, according to the video, that doesnt seem to be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In my (poor sorry!) example I am spilling water from the northmost cell and it flows to the other cells 1 unit at a time. adding 1 unit to the new cell and subtracting 1 from the previous. Because of this it kind of piles up like sand instead of water. It would be best even if all available cells filled to 1 before starting to go to 2. What I wanted is 1 click flows 1 unit of water through the system, and in this setup it ends after 72 clicks and these 18 cells at 4 capacity. ( on the bottom of the video I posted I have a label "total water=" which is keeping track of wateramount in the system

Comment: Perfect that's what I was looking for thanks so much!